# Dimensionality reduction in text data for KNN

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining, sentiment-analysis, knn, dimensionality-reduction

I have text data (tweets) classified as positive, neutral and negative. I want to test if KNN will do better for reduced dimensions. I tested KNN with different CountVectorizers (different max_feature) from sklearn, but it doesnt really do anything. Is there a point in applying for example PCA or manifold? If yes, how to apply these to text data?

Comment: What does "really do anything" mean? Low accuracy? It would be helpful if you could provide some more details.

Comment: Accuracy for different ma_feature value in count vectorizers are rougly the same (0.61-0.64). But I wonder is reducing dimensionality in any other way that would keep the data locally stable  would be more efficient in KNN. My point is to test it, but i dont know how to work with text data in terms of reducing dimensionality.